# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

**Здесь вы не увидите ни на что (не)способного человека.**

Answer (score 1):

Здесь - раздельно. Здесь отрицание, которое усиливается конструкцией "ни на что". Такая конструкция положительное качество усиливать не может. Да и вообще, если есть усилительное "ни", прямо относящееся к определению с "не", то это "не" почти всегда раздельно. Это стоило упомянуть, т.к. при обычных "зависимых словах" исключений больше.

Answer (score 0):

Писать стоит раздельно, я считаю. В предложении явное отрицание способностей человека.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на этот вопрос содержится в школьной программе по русскому языку: "Частица НЕ пишется со словом раздельно, если этому слову предшествует или от него зависит отрицательное местоимение или наречие"

Comment: К сожалению или к счастью, школьная программа частенько жертвует точностью ради поняности.  
Хотя в данном случае "детское" правило действует.